# How can admins see which users authorized Facebook application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it possible to see which users authorized a Facebook app, assuming you're the app admin?

If so, how?

We would rather not store our own database of authorized users. We prefer something similar to  Google Analytics, except where we can log in and see a snapshot of who has authorized the app (diff from daily/monthly active users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information isn't available from the API. I'm not even sure its available on the website. What I do for my app to get this info is log the info on my server (access token, user id) so that I can query it later.